# Print 'x' amount of items 'y' times?

Tags: python, list

So, I'm trying to have an item for list1 printed once, then the first element of item2 dictates how many items from list 3 are printed, then the next loop around, it starts where it left off. Then repeat until I run out of items from list1.. I think I have all the lists formatted right because list1 is a list of strings, list2 is a list of integers and list3 is another list of strings

```
prevval = 0
for i in list1:
    print(i)
    for j in list2:
        val = j
        print(list3[prevval:val])
        prevval = val
```

it prints out the first x amount of items from list 3, a total of 8 times (which is how many elements are in list 2)

Sample:

```
list1 = ["test","please"]
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list3 = ["hard", "to", "come", "up","with","values"]
```

it will print:

```
test
hard to
hard to
hard to
hard to come
```

expected would be:

```
test
hard to
please
come up with values
```

etc

Comment: `list`, `list`, `list3`... what are they?

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: List1 is a list of strings, list2 is a list of integers, list3 is a list of strings

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn But the actual lists?, so i can copy?

Comment: it prints out the first x amount of items from list 3, a total of 8 times (which is how many elements are in list 2)

Comment: Do you want `val += j` instead of `val = j`?

Comment: added all the info into the post

Comment: where does that `1` come from in your desired output?

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn The current output you put there is not the output of the code for me.

Comment: I changed the desired output to be right, and what output did you get?

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn I had: `test
['hard', 'to']
['come', 'up', 'with', 'values']
[]
please
[]
[]
[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each word in `list1` you want to print a slice of `list3` determined by the corresponding value in `list2`. You can do that by zipping `list1` and `list2` and computing the appropriate slices:

```
list1 = ["test","please"]
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list3 = ["hard", "to", "come", "up","with","values"]

prevval = 0
for w1, i in zip(list1, list2):
    print(w1)
    if prevval < len(list3): 
        print(list3[prevval:prevval + i])
        prevval += i
```

**Output**

```
test
['hard', 'to']
please
['come', 'up', 'with', 'values']
```

If you want to format the lists as a string, you can use `join`:

```
' '.join(print(list3[prevval:prevval + i]))
```

Comment: Might you not get an `IndexError` if `prevval + i >= len(list3)`? (eg. a short `list3`)

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner No. You'll just get a slice till the end of the list. From the doc *"However, out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully when used for slicing"* (this was for strings but applies to lists too: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 0):

```
prevval = 0

val=0

for i in list1:

    print(i)

    val=list2[val]

    print(list3[prevval:val])

    prevval = val
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Always add a bit of explanation. Beyond that: make sure to nicely format indent **all** of your input, instead of just dumping  text on others.

Answer (score 0):

This will destroy `list3`:

```
list1 = ["test","please"]
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list3 = ["hard", "to", "come", "up","with","values"]

l1_idx = 0
l2_idx = 0

while l3_idx < len(list3):
  print(list1[l1_idx])
  l1_idx += 1
  outarr = []
  for x in range(list2[l2_idx]):
    try:
      outarr.append(list3.pop(0))
    except IndexError:
      break
  print(" ".join(outarr))
  l2_idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one here:

```
prevval=0
for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
   print(x)
   print(' '.join(list3[prevval:prevval+y]))
   prevval+=y
```

The output is:

```
test
hard to
please
come up with values
```

`zip` them and iterate over, add `prevval` as usual, and remove the inner loop, that's all the changes, note that it makes it shorter (by far).

Comment: The problem with omitting the `if` statement is that if `list3 = ["hard"]` it'll print an empty list (or blank line in this case) which I'm not sure is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python

list1 = ["test","please"]
list2 = [2, 4, 6]
list3 = ["hard", "to", "come", "up","with","values"]

for i in list1:
    print(i)
    s = []
    for j in range(list2.pop(0)):
        s.append(list3.pop(0))
    print(" ".join(s))
```

Output:

```
test
hard to
please
come up with values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['test', 'please', 'this', 'works']
list2 = [2,4,6]
list3 = tmp = ['hard', 'to', 'come', 'up', 'with', 'values', 'because', 'it', 'is', 'simple', 'with', 'python']
for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    try:
       print(tmp[:list2[index]])
       tmp = tmp[list2[index]:]
    except:
       break
```